# How can I check the size of MS PDW table?

Tags: sql-server

The way of checking the table space size in MS SQLServer I've known is

```
sp_spaceused [tablename]
```

OR

```
SELECT 
    t.NAME AS TableName,
    p.rows AS RowCounts,
    SUM(a.total_pages) * 8 AS TotalSpaceKB, 
    SUM(a.used_pages) * 8 AS UsedSpaceKB, 
    (SUM(a.total_pages) - SUM(a.used_pages)) * 8 AS UnusedSpaceKB
FROM 
    [sys].[tables] t
INNER JOIN      
    [sys].[indexes] i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    [sys].[partitions] p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id
INNER JOIN 
    [sys].[allocation_units] a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
WHERE 
    t.NAME NOT LIKE 'dt%' 
    AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0
    AND i.OBJECT_ID > 255
GROUP BY 
    t.Name, p.Rows
ORDER BY 
    t.Name
```

But I can't find the [sys].[allocation_units] table in MS PDW (SQL Server 2012 Parallel Data Warehouse).

So it is hard to check the table size.

How can I know the table space size ??

Comment: This article talks about the PDM DMVs and how they're named slightly different.  It's worth reviewing: http://beyondrelational.com/modules/24/syndicated/916/Posts/19399/parallel-data-warehouse-pdw-tip-useful-appliance-queries.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
USE AdventureWorksPDW2012;
DBCC PDW_SHOWSPACEUSED ( "AdventureWorksPDW2012.dbo.FactInternetSales" );
DBCC PDW_SHOWSPACEUSED ( "AdventureWorksPDW2012..FactInternetSales" );
DBCC PDW_SHOWSPACEUSED ( "dbo.FactInternetSales" );
DBCC PDW_SHOWSPACEUSED ( FactInternetSales );
```

Comment: While it's a good solution, first you should explain why of this solution, but in case of a lot of tables (like more than 5 or even 300) this solution becomes inefficient.